# Most efficient way to concatenate and filter many .jsonl files

Tags: python, json, performance

I'm running into a performance issue with how I take logs to concatenate and then filter them to only the information I need. I didn't expect this to be an issue, but it is becoming clear that my hacky approach is taking way, way too long (like in the 6-12 hour range, which is unacceptable to me)

I have about 70K .jsonl files in a folder, each with about 200 lines, and I'm trying to pull only certain fields from them and concatenate them into a single file. I'm only pulling three fields and they are short strings so it is not extremely memory intensive, but it is just taking waaayyyy too long with my method, and I know there has to be a much faster way.

Right now, I'm just using pandas since I am familiar with it and it takes me very little time to write up a script - here is my current function:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

def read_files_and_concatenate(parent_directory):
    final_df = pd.DataFrame()
    count = 0
    for file in Path(parent_directory).iterdir():
        log_file = pd.read_json(str(file), dtype=str, lines=True)
        final_df = pd.concat([final_df, log_file[['record_id', 
                                                  'updated_at', 
                                                'updates_submitted']]])
        print('{} logs in part, {} logs in 
              master, {} files concatenated'.format(len(log_file), 
                                                 len(final_df), count))
        count += 1
return final_df
```

Again, memory isn't an issue here because each log being concatenated is only a small string - even with millions of lines, it's only a few hundred MB. I'm most familiar with python, so I would prefer a solution using it, but if there is some sort of .json command line tool or bash command that does this kind of thing efficiently I'm open for those suggestions too.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: You can use `jq` for this, something like (untested): `cat *.jsonl | jq '.[] | select ( .record_id | .updated_at | .updates_submitted)' > out` - I'm sure this is wrong but it gives you an idea how easy it is. Check out here for more info: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: Looks awesome, I'll check out the performance tomorrow and get back to you. Thanks for the suggestion!